# Does getline work inside of a while loop? C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, while-loop

When user types quit it doesn't stop for some reason ? Any ideas what I am doing wrong ? C++

```
vector<string> v;
while(true)
{
    cout << "Enter a string (quit to stop)" << endl;
    getline(cin,names);
    if(names=="quit")break;
    v.push_back(names);
    addFullName(names);
}

void addFullName(string str)
{

    string word = " ";
    int pos = str.find(word);
    string s2;  
    string s3 = str.substr(pos+word.length());
    string s4 = str.substr(pos = 0, pos);
    s2 += s3 + ", " + s4;
    v.push_back(s2);    
}
```

Comment: what is `names` ?

Comment: Please update your question and put all relevant informatrion there. Read about this: [MCVE].

Comment: Add the definition to the code, please. Unsure if you mean std::string or a `char *`

Comment: For some reason, when I take out the function addFullName(names); the while loops actually works.

Comment: @ChrisAshkar That's too broad. `const char*` or `std::string`?

Comment: Then maybe the problem is in `addFullNames`. Please show us a [mcve]

Comment: @Rakete1111 std string.

Comment: Where and how is `v` defined ? Please post a [mcve], otherwise your question will be downvoted and finally closed.

Comment: vector<string> v; is defined as a global variable

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `std::getline` inside a while-loop. In fact, you can use it as the sentinel for a while-loop. For instance, if you're reading from a file, the following will read every line (and print it) until the EOF:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream fin{"some_file.txt"};

while(std::getline(fin, line)) {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

---

As for your problem, if `names` is a `std::string`, it should work. If it isn't (i.e., it's a `char *`), you'll need to include the buffer size. Please use `std::string` if you can, though.